# How to add acustom plug-in to a java project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a custom plug-in and i want to add to add that dependency to my java program.

**How do I do that?**

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins can only be used by Eclipse or some other Eclipse RCP. You can't use them from plain Java programs. Perhaps you should explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to refactor a classname and its object throughout the project
e.g., if I have a statement
ClassName object = object.getSomeMethod();

I want to provide an option to refactor this to something like

String value = Utils.getSomeMethod(); (Just an example)

to achieve this we are writing a plug-in, and want to use that in my project

Comment: You need to specify it in your other projects' `MANIFEST.MF`